# 70's tic-tac-toe 'like' game with a pendulum

Tags: identify-this-game, tic-tac-toe

I remember receiving a game in the early 70's for Christmas that came in a pretty big box (about 18"-24" square). There was a pole that had a tether-ball with about a foot of cord and a ball that was smaller than a pool ball. The center of the base there was a plastic 'holder' that contained a 3x3 matrix of blocks. Each block had an 'X' or an 'O' (like in tic-tac-toe). You would swing the tether ball and attempt to knock a block from the center- thus getting the spot for your 'X' or 'O'. Maybe Vincent Price was pictured on the cover of the box- not sure. Anyone else remember this game?

Comment: Could you be misremembering it as Vincent Price, the horror actor, when it said Fisher-Price, the toy and game company?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a a game from 1972 called [Skittle tac toe](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24981/skittle-tac-toe) with two attached pictures (taken from the same BBG link): [image][image]

The guy on the cover is Don Adams (Get Smart - credit to geneo) and there is a video commercial about the game as well.

https://youtu.be/LiLogFT0pI8?si=LQG1FU25pWTcxs7g

Comment: Nice find. FWIW: That company made a series of Skittle games with various thematic scoring alternatives: https://flashbak.com/believedon-adams-pitch-man-skittle-games-50303/

Comment: WOW- that is the game. It is Don Adams (Get Smart) not Vincent Price. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Table Skittles with a tac-tac-toe theme added on for scoring instead of more traditional scoring options.

The Skittles games come in a variety of configurations, some with 9 pins arranged in a 3x3 grid, so it wouldn't be a stretch to try to replace the knocked pins (or whatever) with a marker for tic-tac-toe.

Sample of one version with a 3x3 arrangement:

[image: Skittles game]

From
https://tomsk3000.com/product/1960s-table-skittles-game-by-chad-valley-england/